# Gaussian Processes gives non usable results on a simple 1 D problem

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gaussian-process

I want to use gaussian processes on a simple 1-D Problem but it doesnt work correctly. I am not sure why it doesnt work like expected. See the following code and the plot which shows the datapoints and the mean prediction.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

X = np.linspace(start=0, stop=10, num=1_000).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.squeeze(X * np.sin(X))

X = np.array(df)
y = labels

scaler = StandardScaler()
X= scaler.fit_transform(X)
noise_std = 0.75

rng = np.random.RandomState(1)
y_train_noisy = y + rng.normal(loc=0.0, scale=noise_std, size=y.shape)


from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF

kernel = 1 * RBF()
gaussian_process = GaussianProcessRegressor(
    kernel=kernel, alpha=noise_std**2, n_restarts_optimizer=9
)
gaussian_process.fit(X, y_train_noisy)
mean_prediction, std_prediction = gaussian_process.predict(X, return_std=True)

plt.plot(X, y, label=r"$f(x) = x \sin(x)$", linestyle="dotted")
plt.errorbar(
    X,
    y_train_noisy,
    noise_std,
    linestyle="None",
    color="tab:blue",
    marker=".",
    markersize=10,
    label="Observations",
)
plt.plot(X, mean_prediction, label="Mean prediction")
plt.fill_between(
    X.ravel(),
    mean_prediction - 1.96 * std_prediction,
    mean_prediction + 1.96 * std_prediction,
    color="tab:orange",
    alpha=0.5,
    label=r"95% confidence interval",
)
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel("$x$")
plt.ylabel("$f(x)$")
_ = plt.title("Gaussian process regression on a noisy dataset")
```

[image]

I am new to gaussian processes so i dont know how to resolve this problem. I was especting a smooth curve.

Comment: What is the source of `df` in the line `X = np.array(df)` ? And likewise where does `labels` come from in `y = labels` ?

Comment: This is a plotting problem, not a problem with the gaussian process itself. You probably do not have your X values in the right order.

Answer (score 1):

The example you posted works fine for me if you remove `X = np.array(df)` and `y = labels`.

The data should be ordered if you are plotting lines, otherwise the lines will zigzag between the unordered points. Sort the x values, and plot sorted x vs sorted f(x).

[image]